# Copy form fields values and paste them in another form/tab?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, firefox, autofill

Is there a browser extension for Firefox or Chrome that can copy the form fields values from one page and paste/autofill them into another page/tab containing the same or similar form? Any suggestions for another way to achieve it are welcome too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way, fairly quick. I used Firefox and the [Autofill Forms](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/?src=search) addon. Having the two forms, let's call them "form1" from where I want to copy the values and paste them in "form2", I had to execute manually the following steps:

- Open form1
- Right click in an input field and choose "Add complete form as profile ..."
- Delete the "Site url" text and press Enter
- Open form2
- Press "Alt+J" to fill out the form.

Comment: I'm using Django admin and trying to copy fields from staging to production...this saved a lot of time! Not a perfect solution if the dropdown menu items aren't in the same order, but otherwise really nice.

Comment: had the same use case :)

Answer (score 4):

From the Chrome side...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-form/jibbpldanfkhgddfjpdmhdleneofgkne

Right click and copy one form, right click and paste the other. I've used a few extensions for copying forms to and fro and they usually copy ALL forms on the page and then restore a bunch of data you don't want to restore. This one grabs just what you want and restores it.